# CakePHP table is missing even when it exists

Tags: php, cakephp

i tried googling and searched for an answer here too,

**The Problem**

CakePHP can't find a table even when it exist.

**What I tried:**

1. Clearing the cache folder
2. Verifying the name of the table & the connection string.
3. Adding useTable = "urls"

**The code**

```
class Url extends AppModel {
    public function add_url($the_url,$the_content,$title) {
        $this->create();
        $this->set('url', $the_url );
        $this->set('content', $the_content );
        $this->set('title', $title );
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

**The error:**

> Missing Database Table
>
> Error: Table urls for model Url was not found in datasource default.

Perhaps someone knows the answer to this?

Comment: check if disabling the cache (in `core.php`) fixes the problem - if it does it _is_ cache related. Otherwise check what [the db returns](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1112) - does it contain other tables, or does it contain _no_ tables?

Comment: Disabled the cache, didn't helped. Printed the tables, it does shows all of the other tables that exist. But not 'urls' table. :(

Comment: @AD7six , epic fail on my part. The connection string was pointing to older db , your advice to print the db tables helped me to figure out that i'm stupid. Post your answer so i can mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Check for cache problems

One way to identify (or eliminate) cache related problems is to simply [disable the cache](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/core.php#L156):

```
/**
 * Turn off all caching application-wide.
 *
 */
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
```

If this solves the problem, it's necessary to take a closer look at why previous efforts to clear the cache apparently failed. If file-based caching is used ensure all files under `tmp` are deleted, if a different cache store is being used ensure it's actually being cleared.

### Is there one table missing, or no table reported at all?

Another relatively common cause for what is described is for the database user to not have permission to list the tables in the given database, this can be checked for in the same way [a model does it](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1112):

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
debug($db->listSources());
die;
```

If there are no tables listed at all - check the connection credentials and ensure that, for example, there are no permission related problems. Execute [the same sql that CakePHP is executing](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php#L217) via the cli and ensure that the result is as expected:

```
$ mysql -uuser -ppassword databasename
mysql> show tables from foo;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_foo   |
+-----------------+
| posts           |
| urls            |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If there *are* tables listed - then double, triple and quadruple check the connection credentials as the relevant code is working as expected and the table that is missing does not in fact exist in the database the application is connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

For cakephp 2.*: Delete the file named `myapp_cake_model_[Database Name]_list` in the folder `app/tmp/cache/models` will solve problem in my case.