# CakePHP Error: SQLSTATE[42S02] table not found - but exist

Tags: mysql, cakephp

You might read this question every day so i tried another Stackoverflow's answer before asking:

[CakePHP table is missing even when it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249650/cakephp-table-is-missing-even-when-it-exists/19251788#19251788)

Anyways. The table i try to select data from does exist (quadra-checked uppercase/lowercase!) and it gets also listed via `$db->->listSources()`.

---

Here's a screenshot of the query, the message and the last result from listing all Datasource's tables:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdhcV.png

---

**Note:** If i run this query in PHPMyAdmin manually it works fine. I would say its impossible to get the pictures output at one time in a view - now its up to you to tell me the opposite. By the way: I am pretty sure to use the correct Datasource.

I should tell additionally that the mysql-server is hosted on another platform. Since i can use it for my localhost-phpmyadmin if i modify the config.inc.php i can promise it is no Firewall-Problem.

Comment: have you cross checked the database names?

Comment: I did. Also i guess it should throw an "unkown db" - error instead if this would cause the error. Beside that fact, it's listing all tables correctly before (as you can see on the picture)

Comment: have you cleared the cache from tmp folder?

Comment: Fixed it!

The mistake was to execute the Query from the local Model.

Here's the code:

$conn =  ConnectionManager::getDataSource('myDB');
$conn->query($query);    // instead of $this->query($query);

Comment: What is Fu? no abuse plz.

Comment: Please @xcy7e웃, write it as an answer. I found also that mistake, and it'll be good for everybody just having it there. I did it for you, if you write I'll remove my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written in behalf of xcy7e:

The mistake was to execute the Query from the local Model. Here's the code:

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('myDB'); 
$conn->query($query); 
// instead of $this->query($query);
```